# ADFS Single Sign On - Error with decryption

Tags: c#, encryption, adfs

Been working on the SSO, however found it to be working fine without using a certificate. But when a certificate is added, then I get an error 'ID1044: An encrypted security token was received at the relying party which could not be decrypted. Configure the relying party with a suitable decryption certificate. Current relying party decryption certificate info:
No Certificate Configured'. Please guide me on how to proceed.

The error is on the code;
fam.GetSecurityToken(request)

Also, added the thumbprint in the web.config (from the decrypt certificate).

Comment: Adds uses two certificates. First, obligatory, for signing. This works for you. Then, you add encryption. This time, ADFS has only the certificate but your client app must have the private key to decrypt the token. Apparently you miss this client certificate.

Comment: I am new to AD FS. Just wanted to know how would I be getting the private key? Also, where will I be getting client certificate?

Comment: You have to be more specific. By "How do I ..." you mean how do You (as a person) do something? Or how's Your code supposed to do that? Literally, "How do I get the private key" - the private key is supposed to be a part of your configuration. It is not clear then if your problem is with the code or with the configuration.

Comment: Well I meant if the private key is available in metadata or should the certificate be exported? All I'm trying to do here  is make the decryption work..

Comment: Private key is never in metadata. That would make no sense. It's the client who has the encryption certificate with private key and the server which only knows the public key. If you only have the server part (the public certificate), it seems the private key of this client is either gone or known by a person who configured your ADFS

Comment: Generated a certificate with a private key and configured the same in the relying party encryption tab. After which started getting an error 'MSIS3014: The encryption certificate of the relying party trust..'. For which I happen to execute a  powershell command ' -EncryptionCertificateRevocationCheck None'. Currently getting the same error as before 'ID4036: The key needed to decrypt the encrypted security token could not be resolved from the following security key identifier'